# Property 'PolicyEnforcement' is 'ReadOnly'

Tags: .net, vb.net, wcf

I'm trying to assign a 'Never' value to the

I am trying to assign `ExtendedProtectionPolicy.PolicyEnforcement = Never` to my `binding` object but I get an error:

```
Error   1   Property 'PolicyEnforcement' is 'ReadOnly'.
```

Object declaration:

```
Dim binding As New WSHttpBinding()
binding.Name = "WSHttpBinding_ITest"
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 10240
binding.ReliableSession.Enabled = True
binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None

'Error below binding.Security.Transport.ExtendedProtectionPolicy.PolicyEnforcement = System.Security.Authentication.ExtendedProtection.PolicyEnforcement.Never
```

Any ideas how to assign the 'Never' value to it?

Comment: Maybe something like: `binding.Security.Transport.ExtendedProtectionPolicy = New System.Security.Authentication.ExtendedProtection.ExtendedProtectionPolicy(System.Security.Authentication.ExtendedProtection.PolicyEnforcement.Never)`.

Comment: @mark Yes, you are right. You can answer the question and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `ExtendedProtectionPolicy` is immutable, you need to replace it with a new instance, configured as desired, instead of updating the existing one, e.g.

```
binding.Security.Transport.ExtendedProtectionPolicy =
    New System.Security.Authentication.ExtendedProtection.ExtendedProtectionPolicy(
        Syste‌​m.Security.Authentication.ExtendedProtection.PolicyEnforcement.Never
    )
```